# Sentbox item load event handler outlook addin in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a outlook-addin from which I am able to catch the sent event handler. Now I want to catch the load event handler. After I send a mail it will go to sent box. I want to handle that loading of mail item event into sent box. I think I have to use Application.Itemload() but not sure exactly. If so how do I have to do that in C#.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "load"? Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I want to do certain task after the mail has been sent. I  want the mail item that is actually sent which goes to sent box. I then want to pick that mail and do my task(Like inserting that mail into repository) .To do this i want to get to know immediately after it reaches to sent box . Can you suggest me how to get this handle?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder.